# retrieve javascript variable in php variable variable

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I am trying to dynamically create variables in `javascript`. In my `PHP` code I already dynamically create variables from `SQL` output which gives me `$res1`, `$res2`, etc. Now I want to use these in my `javascript` but of course I cannot hardcode it for I can never know how many of the `$res` variables the `PHP` will generate. 
I have the feeling I am already fairly close though. I have the following:

```
var i=1;
while (i<=count) {
    var name = "<?php ${"res".$_GET['i']} ?>";
}
```

Comment: Try passing the variables back in an array, then do a foreach through them.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414408/how-to-store-a-string-in-a-javascript-variable-that-has-single-quotes-and-double/12414551#12414551. It may help you.

Comment: Thank you guys, your reactions helped me and i've got it working now by using an array and using json_encode to use the array in javascript. <br/>
Sebcap26, it is indeed related to passing variables from php to javascript but as you probably see my problem is passing variables + combining javascript and php variables to create a javascript variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php will be ran once after the server request, so `$_GET[i]` will only have one value for the entire loop. Which I'm presuming is not your desired effect.

Try handling the variables on the backend and pushing them all into a array then sending that to the browser.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var name = data[i];
}
```

where data is an array sent back from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Put the PHP data in an array. Then you can convert the PHP array to a JS array with `json_encode()`:

```
var res = <?php echo json_encode($res) ?>;
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    var name = res[i];
    // Do something with name
}
```